# AWS Route 53 DNS does not resolve

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I am developing [Mycroft Nutrition](http://www.mycroftnutrition.com) and am attempting to switch my domain from pointing at Heroku to an AWS endpoint because I just switched to AWS Lambda for a serverless architecture. My new endpoint is https://usfqa3q0sg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/, which is working fine, and I have set my DNS accordingly: [image: DNS settings]

However, [mycroftnutrition.com](http://mycroftnutrition.com) still is not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction to getting my domain working?

## Update

I created a custom domain for my API as per @matt-healy's recommendation and now have this: [image]

I set my DNS to be this but still have no luck: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your DNS entry to point to:

usfqa3q0sg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev

which is not a valid domain.

What you want to do is set up a Custom Domain Name in API Gateway which will map the domain name address to the "dev" stage of your API endpoint.

For more information you can view the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I followed the docs but think I'm missing something obvious. Just updated my post

Comment: @BenjaminLee what do your Base Path Mappings look like?

Comment: Currently, there are no base path mappings.

Comment: You will need to add a base path mapping for "/" pointing to the "dev" stage of your API